# Why is there an error to this code?

Tags: java

Why does the compiler signal me an error when class MyExcept extends Exception but it doesn't when it extends RuntimeException?

```
class MyExcept extends Exception{}
class Main{
public static void efect(int x){
    if(x==0)throw new MyExcept();
}

public static void main(String argv[]){
    int x=0;
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        try{
            for(int k=0;k<2;k++){
                x++;
                efect(k);
            }
        }catch(MyExcept e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(x);
 }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the error? I'm assuming it'll be saying something like "unhandled exception MyExcept". Normal exceptions you need to declare that they may be thrown in the method signature where you're throwing it from, whereas with runtime exceptions you do not

Comment: Doesn't give me any compile error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is in efect method: As you are throwing MyExcept(), the method efect should have throws clause. Like :

```
public static void efect(int x) throws MyExcept
```

You are not getting compiler error, when you are changing the extends to RuntimeException because Runtime exceptions are unchecked exceptions and compiler doesnot check for it at compile time.